# Was -NoADLookup Removed from New-SPOMigrationPackage?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, api

In the SharePoint migration API, you use the SharePoint Online Management Console, in 2015-June they added the `-NoADLookup` parameter to the `New-SPOMigrationPackage` command.

It appears as though the 2016-Sept update to the SPOMC no longer has this flag, I'm getting an error

> "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'NoAdLookup'."

Can anyone confirm?
Does anyone have a link to the release notes for the 2016-Sept SPOMC update?
Does anyone have a link to the previous release download?

Comment: Someone responded to me elsewhere, it was removed from this release, no indication of why. I do now have a copy of the old install files, I will keep them around for a bit, just PM me here if you need them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This parameter was replaced with -NoAzureADLookup

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68271)

Comment: @Gaurravs I think it actually answer the question at hand, don't you think?

Comment: answers that don't require clarification from the asker seems to be comments. since thats too short answer, @mwebb could have provide some references as Asker requested. Hence marked

Comment: I'm going to allow it for now, but it would be nice to know how this person knows about the change. I cannot find any release notes or other documentation regarding this change.

Comment: Just checked, it's in the `get-help` for the power shell command.